# Angular, boolean value in a select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, boolean

I want to set a boolean value to true or false using a select here is my code:

```
<select class="span9" ng-model="proposal.formalStoryboard">
<option value="false">Not Included</option>
<option value="true">Included</option>
</select>
```

The value (proposal.formalStoryboard) is set properly to true or false **but the change are not reflected on the select box when the value is already assigned.**

I tried ng-value="true" and ng-value="false" instead of just value but it's not working as well.

Comment: ngValue works fine for me (tested on Angular 1.6)
`<select ng-model="$ctrl.request.invoiced" class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option ng-value="undefined">All</option>
                    <option ng-value="false">Not Invoiced</option>
                   <option ng-value="true">Invoiced</option>
</select>
`

Comment: If you are using angular `>=1.2.0` see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47933431/181569

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**EDIT:** Commentors have pointed out that my original solution did not work as claimed. I have updated the answer to reflect the correct answer given by others below (I cannot delete an accepted answer).

For Angular 1.0.6, consider this HTML:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    <select ng-model="mybool"
            ng-options="o.v as o.n for o in [{ n: 'Not included', v: false }, { n: 'Included', v: true }]">
    </select>
    <p>
        Currently selected: <b>{{ mybool }}</b> opposite: {{ !mybool }}
   </p> 
 </div>
</div>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
function MyCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.mybool = true;
}
```

Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jGfL5/112/) for Angular 1.0.6 and here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisP/moojmocp/1/) for Angular 1.3.14, which is slightly different.

Comment: Hi Chris I got that part working, I putted in bold the problem in my question :)

Comment: @Jerome Ansia: See comment/answer from sza.  You have not posted whatever is causing your problem.  This code works.

Comment: oh ok give my a few minutes I am gonna check this ;)

Comment: @JeromeAnsia, is the code you posted inside an element with `ng-repeat` or a custom directive?  I'm guessing that the `<select>` exists in a different scope.

Comment: no is the same, i am really confuse because I see that you code is working and the other answer as well. I am trying to figure out what is wrong. It's probably linked to my backend or something. I have to check that the value is actually a boolean. That's probably the problem.

Comment: Ok i don't know what was wrong, i converted my value to int, but your code is definitely working so I accept your answer ;)

Comment: This actually doesn't work. I've updated your jsfiddle to show the inverse too: http://jsfiddle.net/jGfL5/14/ This actually sets the value to the string "true" or the string "false" which both evaluate to truthy.

Comment: @BigDong  Does it work in the demo JSFiddle for you? It's working for me.

Comment: @BigDong  The issue relates to the version of AngularJS you are using.  See the updated answer, which links to a demo for Angular 1.3.14.

Comment: ngValue works fine for me (tested on Angular 1.6)
`<select ng-model="$ctrl.request.invoiced" class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option ng-value="undefined">All</option>
                    <option ng-value="false">Not Invoiced</option>
                   <option ng-value="true">Invoiced</option>
</select>
`

Answer (score 59):

Just do like this:

```
<select ng-model="someModel" ng-options="boolToStr(item) for item in [true, false]">
</select>
```

and define:

```
$scope.boolToStr = function(arg) {return arg ? 'Included' : 'Not included'};
```

Comment: nice answer, the only one that really seems to address the difficult part of the question

Comment: To avoid defining boolToStr, I have ng-options="o.v as o.n for o in [{ n: 'No', v: false }, { n: 'Yes', v: true }]"

Comment: Thanks for this answer, by the way! IMO this is the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Aaron Does this work properly for you?  I'm trying it (using Angular 1.3) and although it displays properly, I get a huge error in my stack trace if the var declaration is inlined.  If I define the an options array in the controller and loop over it, it works fine.  Was wondering if you had the same issues.

Comment: @EricB. It works for me inline, with no error printed, and I'm using v1.3.0-beta.2. If you can reproduce the issue in a plunkr I'll see if I can help debug.

Comment: @Aaron Strange.  I've tried to reproduce in a plunkr but can't get the same error in the console.  Will try again and see if I'm doing something wrong in my code.

Comment: @EricB. I've had similar issues reproducing issues with AngularJS in Plunkrs.. I started by pasting my code in, and gradually removing unnecessary stuff until the code was as simple as possible, but still demonstrated the error. *shrug*

Comment: @Aaron - I too have issues with the inline version.  I think a new array is being created each time it's evaluated and causing an endless loop.

Answer (score 34):

Why not just use this?

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="(item?'Included':'Not Included') for item in [true, false]"></select>
```

Comment: Nice. Stores booleans (not Strings) in the model, as desired, and all in one line. There is really no need for a directive or a helper function.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using angularjs version `>= 1.2.0` you will have access to the directive `ng-value`

You can use the `ng-value` on an option element. Your htmls would work like this.

```
<select ng-model="proposal.formalStoryboard">
    <option ng-value="true">Included</option>
    <option ng-value="false">Not Included</option>
</select>
```

It also works on radio and checkboxes.

Comment: this is the simplest answer that works. Confirmed as of june 2018

Comment: easy and simple

Comment: That should be accepted, or at least the most up-voted answer!

Comment: I appreciate the vote. Looks like ngValue only became available in [version 1.2.0](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/ng.directive:ngValue) so can understand why it's not the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a directive for this. As usual, I try to stay away from timeouts and other async operations in preference of a more authoritative and direct control.

```
directives.directive('boolean', function() {
  return {
    priority: '50',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(_, __, ___, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return value == 'true' || value == true;
      });

      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return value && value != 'false' ? 'true' : 'false';
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The priority is set specifically so that it is done prior to any other directives (that usually don't have a priority set, and defaults to `0`)

For example, I use this directive (for a true/false selection) with my `selectpicker` directive that wraps my `select` elements in the `selectpicker` bootstrap plugin.

Edit:

The caveat here, which I forgot to mention, is that your html values need to be string values. What the directive does is translates between the view and the model, keeping the model value in `boolean` and your view in `string` format:

```
%select.selectpicker{ ng: { model: 'modelForm.listed' }, selectpicker: '{ }', boolean: true }
  %option{ value: 'true' } Listed
  %option{ value: 'false' } Unlisted
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work too. Just force the value to be boolean by putting an angular expression in for the value.

```
<select class="span9" ng-model="proposal.formalStoryboard">
    <option value="{{false}}" 
           ng-selected="proposal.formalStoryboard === false">
           Not Included
    </option>
    <option value="{{true}}"
            ng-selected="proposal.formalStoryboard === true">
            Included
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: It works for me, but value of ng model has type string. In my variant after it i have SignalR and it make boolean type for c#, but in many cases it not solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

I created sample for you, please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YXGKE/) out.

Is it what you want to use model to drive the ui binding?

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select class="span9" ng-model="proposal.formalStoryboard">
        <option value="false">Not Included</option>
        <option value="true">Included</option>
    </select>
    <button ng-click="changeValue();">Click</button>
<div>

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.proposal = {};
    $scope.proposal.formalStoryboard = true;

    $scope.changeValue = function () {
        $scope.proposal.formalStoryboard = !$scope.proposal.formalStoryboard;
        console.log($scope.proposal.formalStoryboard);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example has a subtle bug. When you select a value with the select it sets the string. As such, if you change the select box to not included, then click the "Click" button the value won't change. This is because it's gone from the string "false" to the value false.

Answer (score 0):

I had very little success with this frustrating issue. My solution, while not too elegant since it's an additional line of code, solved it every time. This may not work in every application.

```
$scope.myObject.myBooleanProperty = $scope.myObject.myBooleanProperty.toString();
```

Turning it into a "real" string before trying to rebind it to the model displayed on the page allowed it to correctly select the value.

Answer (score 0):

Angular does a strict comparsion between the Value bind to ng-model and the Values in the given Options. The Values given in the initial Question are the Strings "false" and "true".
If the Value of ng-model is of Type bool and defined like {"Value":false}, Angulars strict === comparsion between string and bool does never match so the select-box is empty.

The real Problem is- if you select a Value, the Type changed from bool to string ({"Value":false} --> {"Value":"false"})can cause errors if posted back.

The best Solution for both issues for me was the one of Thiago Passos in this Post.
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/31636437/6319374)

Answer (score -3):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function MyCntrl($scope) {<!--from   ww w . j  a  v a 2s.  c om-->
  $scope.mybool = true;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    <select ng-model="mybool">
        <option value="false">Not Included</option>
        <option value="true">Included</option>
    </select>
    <p>
    Currently selected: {{ mybool }}
   </p>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not the solution to the problem and in fact introduces the same problem in the original question.