# AngularJS does not set any value in a drop-down list for a boolean model field

Tags: angularjs

Despite my model contains a boolean value, below code displays `true`:

```
{{ moduleDAO.includeIntermediate }}
```

the following HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': ModuleDAOForm.includeIntermediate.$invalid}">
    <label for="includeIntermediate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Include Intermediate</label>
    <div id="includeIntermediateControls" class="col-sm-10">
    <select id="includeIntermediate" name="includeIntermediate" class="form-control" ng-model="moduleDAO.includeIntermediate" >
        <option value="">Choose a value</option>
        <option value="false">false</option>
        <option value="true">true</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

renders a drop-down list without any value set, why?

BTW. The above code has been generated by the JBoss Forge AngularJS scaffold plugin.

Comment: Try this solution from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753927/angular-boolean-value-in-a-select-box/31636437#31636437

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like AngularJS has a problem selecting an option before hand if the value is a boolean. It does work however if you use `ng-options` to define your option tags:

*controller*

```
$scope.options = [
    {value: '', label: 'Choose a value'},
    {value: false, label: 'false'},
    {value: true, label: 'true'},
];
```

*html*

```
<select ng-options="o.value as o.label for o in options"></select>
```

But if you do not have access to the code and it's generated automatically for you, this fix might be harder to implement!? Let me know if you can achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would love to be able to find the cause of this problem without changing the above code, because there are a few dozen such drop-down lists in my app.

Comment: I feel your pine, unfortunately, I couldn't make it work defining my own <option> tags. Maybe you can find a hack.

Comment: I don't know if this will work but you could try: $compile($('#includeIntermediate'))($scope). Don't kill me if it does nothing however :)

Comment: thanks for help, finally I have used your original suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Was dealing with this same issue recently..

```
<select ng-model="currentInvite.isLegal">
         <option value="1" ng-selected="currentInvite.isLegal">Yes</option>
         <option value="0" ng-selected="!currentInvite.isLegal">No</option>
</select>
```