# AngularJS Set select option with static options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select element with static options. The select use a `ng-model`, but when the model is set to one of the values of the options, it isn't selected.

Here is the HTML:

```
<select class="modal-textboxes" ng-model="vm.reportPresets.selectedPreset.systemWideAccess">
    <option value=false>User</option>
    <option value=true>System Wide</option>
</select>
```

When `vm.reportPresets.selectedPreset.systemWideAccess` equals `true` or `false`, none of the select options are selected.

Comment: is this what you looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753927/angular-boolean-value-in-a-select-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ngValue` directive

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', [function() {
      this.systemWideAccess = true;
    }]);

})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller as vm">
    <select class="modal-textboxes" ng-model="vm.systemWideAccess">
        <option ng-value="false">User</option>
        <option ng-value="true">System Wide</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess instead of putting the `systemWideAccess` as true just add an extra option

```
 <select class="modal-textboxes" ng-model="vm.systemWideAccess">
     <option ng-value="">--Select--</option>
     <option ng-value="false">User</option>
     <option ng-value="true">System Wide</option>
 </select>
```